# Export CSV admin function

Tags: adminhtml, csv

I have added custom grid on admin side and all columns are displayed correctly. Filters are also working fine. But when I export to CSV, all records are exported and filters are ignored. Please suggest what to do?

Comment: If you inspect the options from the export dropdown, do you see the filters attached at the end of the string url?

Comment: @SamuelComan: I only see below code:  <select style="width:8em;" id="customerGrid_export" name="customerGrid_export">
                            <option value="http://test.com/index.php/admin/customer/exportCsv/key/b3201d61422d93b4e6914922f5cfa645/">CSV</option>
                            <option value="http://test.com/index.php/admin/customer/exportXml/key/e2acfb3992243b23d5a6d26942e10d11/">Excel XML</option>
                        </select>

Comment: Besides the "key" parameter at the end of the URL you should have the "filter" parameter as well. That one is taken from page URL. It depends on how you do the filtering. If it's done by Ajax then make sure the corect Export select is received in the Ajax response. If it's done by page reload, you should have the filter in the browser url as well. You can debug more in this class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`

Comment: @SamuelComan - Thanks for detailed explanation. I will further explore this and let you know.